# Can I open a tradingview chart to a specific date and timeframe using an url only?

Tags: date, url, charts, bar-chart, tradingview-api

I can open APT ASX stock chart to a specific timeframe, eg. 60mins, using URL only in tradingview as below:

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=ASX:APT&interval=60

The question is: can I open ASX:APT chart with 5min timeframe for a specific time, eg. 16th July 2020 using an URL only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I cannot. It is a premier service only.

Comment: Can you share how this is possible with the pro subscription please? Was looking for it but couldn't find it.

Comment: +1 can you clarify this? I just want to set the date on the widget constructor if possible..  but theres no parameter for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Just add &interval=60
The interval has to be in minutes.